# What's wrong with this HTML script?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am creating a website, and when I run the website, then I just get the hole script. This is my script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>default</title>
</head>

<body> 
<p>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br>
&lt;html lang="en-us"&gt;<br>
&lt;head&gt;<br>
&lt;style&gt;<br>
.city {<br>
float: left;<br>
margin: 5px;<br>
padding: 15px;<br>
width: 300px;<br>
height: 300px;<br>
border: 1px solid black;<br>
} <br>
 &lt;/style&gt;<br>
 &lt;/head&gt;<br>
 &lt;body&gt;</p

<p>&lt;h1&gt;Standen voetbalcompetities :&lt;/h1&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;div class="country"&gt;<br>
&lt;h2&gt;Eredivisie&lt;/h2&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;London is the capital city of England.&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,<br>
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;/div&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;div class="city"&gt;<br>
&lt;h2&gt;Premier League (Engeland)&lt;/h2&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;Paris is the capital of France.&lt;/p&gt; <br>
&lt;p&gt;The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,       <br>
with more than 12 million inhabitants.&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;/div&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;div class="city"&gt;<br>
&lt;h2&gt;Tokyo&lt;/h2&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;Tokyo is the capital of Japan.&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;It is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area,<br>
and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;/div&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;/body&gt;<br>
&lt;/html&gt;</p>
```

NOTE: I mailed the script to myself and pasted it in Dreamweaver, maybe that's the reason but I don't know.

Comment: There are many things wrong.  For starters, something (Dreamweaver?) has replaced all of your angle brackets.  What are you trying to figure out?  What's your question?

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. All the HTML tags have been converted to entities. If you are going to mail yourself a script you would be better off attaching the file or pasting it into a text file that you can attach.

Comment: This looks like HTML which is meant to display something that looks like HTML.  If this isn't the original code you wrote, then clearly you should change it back to that.

Comment: @Teempeemm My question is, why I get as output the whole script, and not what I said it should.

Comment: @L.Peters: Well, what do you *expect* the output of this code to be?  This is just HTML, it's going to display *exactly* what it's written to display.

Comment: Is the file extension .html? If not that is a problem. Also what are you expecting to see? Your tags have been converted to html parsable versions of tags, so while an html representation would show <body> your script actually says &lt;body&gt; which is not html code.

Answer (score 0):

What has happened is that your code has been turned from symbols into entities, so that `>` has been turned into `&gt;` and `<` has been turned into `&lt;` , this means that when the browser runs this code, it doesn't recognise the symbols and so doesn't understand the instructions.

**Solution**, you need to get your original code and stop it being made HTMLsafe by whatever method translated the data from `>` to `&gt;` .

Please read [about HTML special characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (ignore the PHP) this should give you a general insight into special characters in HTML, these are characters that have instruction to the browser rather than data to the viewer .

Answer (score 0):

The characters that looks like `&lt;` are encoded. You can see that the encoded HTML is mixed in with unencoded HTML. This is how someone would actually show HTML tags in the browser. So `&lt;` gets converted to `<` when the page is rendered.

From the looks of it this got messed up. Because after you decode the HTML entities, you'll see that you've got a webpage nested within a webpage.

Take a look at this for more info: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref